# Match end phrase with regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I cant seem to get the end "on court 1" to match, it keeps getting matched with the venue capture.  The "on court 1" is optional.  "at New Albany High School" is the venue.  Is there a way to match the ending string to my capture without including the second to last?

```
^(?<minimum>\d*)(?<dash>-)?(\sor\s(?<moreless>more|less)\s?)?(?<maximum>\d*)((?:on\s|\s)+(?<date>[^\s]*)?)?((?:at\s|\s){1}(?<venue>.*)?)?((?:on\s|\s){1}(?<location>.*)?)?
```

It should match the following below

```
1 or more on 3/30/2018 at 3C on 2
1-2 on 3/30/2018 at 3 Court Venue on 2
1 or less on 11/23/1981 at New Albany High School on court 1
1 at 3C on 1
```

Below is the structure

```
minimum (integer, optional)
("-" or " or less " or " or more ") (optional if max/min are available)
maximum (integer, optional)
on {date} (optional)
at {venue} (optional)
on {court} (optional when venue is available)

{min(-, or more , or less ){max}} {on (date)} {at (venue)} {on (court)}
```

Comment: Not the worst question I've ever seen, but you have like 10k reputation, I'd expect a little more effort and maybe some better markdown use. There isn't even an actual question in your question; just statements.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/Nfo3Nt/1)?

Comment: Yes but it matches the "at" which I dont want for venue

Comment: So [this](https://regex101.com/r/2Ldt1E/1)?

Comment: That is it, can you post your answer and explain how it works?

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work with `1-2 on 3/30/2018 at 3 Court Venue on 2`

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/2Ldt1E/2)

Comment: Now this doesnt work `1 or more on 3/30/2018 at 3C on 2`.  Thanks for the help but it just doesnt look like this regex is very flexible.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/2Ldt1E/3)?

Comment: Date is optional `1 at 3C on 1`, it treats the at as the date now.  Have you gave up @ctwheels?

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/2Ldt1E/4)?

Comment: I took what you did and made some minor tweets so `min-max` is optional, and removed the white space ending in venue.  `^((?<minimum>\d*)(?<dash>-)?(?:\sor\s(?<amount>more|less)\s?)?(?<maximum>\d+)?)?(?:\s*(?:on)?\s*(?<date>[\d/]*)?)?(?:\s*(?:at)?\s+(?<venue>(?:(?!\bon\b).)+)?)?(?:\s(?:on)?\s+(?<location>.*)?)?$`

Comment: Looks like the boundary regex was the work around.  Anyway you can post this answer and state why it worked?

Comment: If you can provide me with a bunch of strings that you need to match, I can probably even minimize your whole pattern. Just post a bunch of sample strings in the regex101 link I provided, save/update it and post it as another comment. I'll take a look and update the regex accordingly :)

Comment: I think I did it, gave you as much as I can

Comment: Do you need to group the dash `-`? Like what groups do you *actually* require?

Comment: Yes the dash is used for a range or specific count if its not there.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2Ldt1E/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/2Ldt1E/8)

```
^(?<minimum>\d+)? *(?<dash>-)? *(?:(?<maximum>\d+)|\bor\s*\b(?<moreless>more|less))? *(?:\bon\s+(?<date>[\d/]+))? *(?:\bat\s+(?<venue>(?:(?!\bon\b).)*\w))? *(?:\bon\s+(?<location>.*))?$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?<minimum>\d+)?` Optionally capture one or more digits into the named capturing group `minimum`
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `(?<dash>-)?` Optionally capture the dash into the named capturing group `dash`
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `(?:(?<maximum>\d+)|\bor\s*\b(?<moreless>more|less))?` Optionally match either of the following

  - `(?<maximum>\d+)` Capture one or more digits into the named capturing group `maximum`
  - `\bor\s*\b(?<moreless>more|less)` Match `or` and capture either `more` or `less` into the named captureing group `moreless`
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `(?:\bon\s+(?<date>[\d/]+))?` Optionally match `on` and capture the date into the named capturing group `date`. The date being composed on one or more digits and `/`
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `(?:\bat\s+(?<venue>(?:(?!\bon\b).)*\S))?` Optionally match `at` and capture the venue into the named capturing group `venue`. The `venue` group will match any character except if the word `on` appears. It matches up to the last non-whitespace character (because of `\S`)
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `(?:\bon\s+(?<location>.*))?` Optionally match `on` and capture the rest of the line into the named capturing group `location`
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Wow, very impressive